# Did I accidentally overwrite the /etc/systemd?

Tags: centos, systemd, mv

I was in `/etc/init.d`. Then I wanted to move the `file.service` so did `mv file.service ../systemd`. The `/etc/systemd` is still there, but the `file.servic`e is nowhere to be found. I am worried that I accidentally renamed the systemd directory, and it would reflect in the next reboot. So in the future, should I just `mv file /directory/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question : no, you did not overwrite `/etc/systemd`.

You moved file `/etc/init.d/file.service` into directory `/etc/rc.d`.

Using the "just mv file /directory" approach you mentioned would indeed avoid this, particularly if /directory was, say, `/root`.

**EDIT** : revised to read /etc/rc.d, per @JdeBP.

Comment: Yes. It (systemd) was root. But I used sudo so I thought I...I'd check again since I ls -la in /etc/systemd the file wasn't there.

Comment: You'll find that the questioner moved it to the name `/etc/rc.d/systemd`.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382143/5132

Comment: @JdeBP - bang on, +1.  I'll update my mistaken answer.  Thx.